# Make a check for a color change button

Tags: java, colors, jframe, actionlistener, mouselistener

So basicly i got a project ongoing and i need some help. It is a game where you have 25 rounded buttons that when pressed change color. So and i colored the buttons around the button pressed (max. 4) the same color to make the little puzzle game more difficult to finish. when i want to press another button the color should change back so when the passively color changed button is red then it should change back when it is passively color changed again if you know what i mean.

Here is my Code (Main Class) because other one is not needed:
`

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public JButton[][] Buttons = new JButton[5][5]; // 5x5 Button Array

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Frame();
    }

    public Frame() {

        initGui();
    }

    // Checkt ob alle Buttons rot sind
    public boolean allButtonsAreRed() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                if (Buttons[i][j].getForeground() != Color.RED) {

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void initGui() {

        // Frame Settings
        setTitle("25er Puzzle");
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Layout für den Frame
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aufgabe: Klicken Sie, bis alle Kreise rot sind!");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                JButton button = new JButton();

                // Button Settings
                button.setBorderPainted(true);
                button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                button.setOpaque(true);
                button.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(200));
                button.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                // Integer I und J werden an Button übergeben
                Buttons[i][j] = button;

                // Buttons werden zum Frame geaddet
                add(Buttons[i][j]);
                
                // Mouse Listener für Button Clicks
                Buttons[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

                        // Farbe vom Button zu neuer Farbe setzen
                        Color newColor = (button.getForeground().equals(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ? Color.RED
                                : Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

                        // Neue Farbe der Buttons setzen
                        button.setForeground(newColor);

                        // Sucht die Position des geklickten Buttons
                        int clickedRow = -1;
                        int clickedCol = -1;
                        
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            
                            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                                
                                if (Buttons[i][j] == button) {
                                    
                                    clickedRow = i;
                                    clickedCol = j;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (clickedRow >= 0 && clickedCol >= 0) {

                            // Färbt den oberen Button
                            if (clickedRow > 0) {
                                
                                Buttons[clickedRow - 1][clickedCol].setForeground(Color.RED);
                            }

                            // Färbt den linken Button
                            if (clickedCol > 0) {
                                
                                Buttons[clickedRow][clickedCol - 1].setForeground(Color.RED);
                            }

                            // Färbt den rechten Button
                            if (clickedCol < 4) {
                                
                                Buttons[clickedRow][clickedCol + 1].setForeground(Color.RED);
                            }
                            // Färbt den unteren Button
                            if (clickedRow < 4) {
                                
                                Buttons[clickedRow + 1][clickedCol].setForeground(Color.RED);
                            }
                        }

                        // Ausgabe der Nachricht (Sieg)
                        if (allButtonsAreRed()) {

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, "Herzlichen Glückwunsch, du hast gewonnen!");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I don’t see anything happening when I click the buttons.  Did you mean to call `setBackground` rather than setForeground?  That aside, it is not correct to add a MouseListener to a JButton.  Use [addActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) to be notified when a button is pressed.  (Believe it or not, button activation is more complex than just detecting a click.)

Comment: i didn't add an ActionListener. I got the solution. Thank you anyway.